# Oracle query that returns columns of a certain type

Tags: oracle10g

Is it possible to write an oracle query that returns all columns which are of type 'timestamp'?

Something like this -

```
Select table_name, column_name
FROM dba_tab_columns
WHERE table_name like 'EST_%' 
AND column_type = 'timestamp'; //Here select columns only of type 'timestamp'
```

Comment: Are you aware that `dba_ind_columns` returns columns that are part of an *index*? It does not show (all) table columns. To answer your question: yes, it's possible to write such a query. What exactly is your question?

Comment: yes! right after asking the question I found that the table I should refer is `dba_tab_columns` and I can use the `DATA_TYPE` column to check the column datatype.

Comment: You probably want: table_name like 'EST\_%' escape '\'

Comment: or `table_name like 'EST\_%' escape '\'`

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp and @David Aldridge: what exactly is this for? i am new to oracle, so i am not sure what `EST\_%' escape '\'` does. Does `_` have a special meaning in oracle?

Comment: It has special meaning for the `LIKE` operator. http://psoug.org/reference/wildcards.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking into the wrong table - `dba_ind_columns` instead of `dba_tab_columns`.

The query is pretty straightforward -

```
Select table_name, column_name
FROM dba_tab_columns
WHERE table_name like 'EST\_%' ESCAPE '\' AND DATA_TYPE = 'TIMESTAMP(6)';
```